# How to get Kafka consumers to subscribe to new Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a couple of Kafka consumers subscribed to a topic and need to add some partitions. I'm playing around in the staging environment and add some new partitions. My understanding of Kafka is that they should automatically rebalance and they subscribe to the new partitions. Except they don't, restarting doesn't help. Each time I've done this (twice now) magically overnight the consumers subscribe to the new partitions.

If I create a new test group in a console it subscribes to the new partitions fine. But subscribing with the existing group id in the console, rebalances the workers but doesn't include the new partitions.

Why are they not subscribing when the partitions are created? And what is happening overnight that is causing them to start seeing the new partitions?

Comment: How did you add the partitions? Can you also show the code of the consumers?

Comment: Let's say you have 2 partitions and you are adding third one.Maybe your producers are producing messages just on existing 2 partitions(if you implemented partitioner or maybe you always send keys that send messages to existing partitions). So when you start new consumer group with 2 consumers, they take that 2 partitions. But, when you add new partition, no message is produced in new partition, so you cannot read anything from it. This is just guessing since we don't have any info about your code and producer/consumer/broker config.

Comment: Kafka is hosted on Aiven and partitions were added in the web console. Producers automatically started sending message to new partition this was confirmed in the Aiven console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, clients (consumers and producers) refresh their metadata every 5 minutes. This is determine by `metadata.max.age.ms`.

In your example, consumers will find new partitions only when refreshing their metadata. So you either need to set this setting to a lower value or wait a bit.

Comment: Restarting processes after waiting five minutes added the partitions